# How to detect device ids to unregister on server with GCM Android push

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented everything related to GCM but this one last thing is giving me trouble. Simply, I want to stop sending to devices that no longer have app - remove their registration IDs.

The problem is that I am using registration_ids variable that allows sending to multiple devices at once. I could possibly send 1 by 1 and then I would obviously know which devices to remove. I have isolated sending to 2 DeviceIds - one is registered and one is not. Sure enough here is the response I get from Google:

```
{
   "multicast_id":4688510806873974237,
   "success":1,
   "failure":1,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[
      {"error":"NotRegistered"},
      {"message_id":"0:1459152002041797%5c073a337cbfbb56"}
   ]
}
```

How can I deduce from that response which devices I need to unregister from future GCM pushes?

Answer (score 3):

While typing question and formatting response JSON I've noticed that results array has error field for first registration. After [reading GCM reference page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) in more detail it seems that you'll get entry in results for each message sent.

So in my case, I have `"failure":1` and then for first message in `results` I got `{"error":"NotRegistered"}` and that can tell me I need to remove that device from senders list.

In case you are wondering `canonical_ids` is for case when device id needs to be updated in your database, in case where that is `canonical_ids > 0` you'll get `registration_id` in `results` array.

Comment: Great solution. But there can be one unhandled case. What will you do for a single device, where i first install it for a particular user say XYZ, later I uninstall, install and logged in with user say PQR. If I push a notification for XYZ user, I won't get any failure because app is installed but the user logged in is PQR so it will be delivered to the user PQR.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal This has more to do with how you associate `registrationToken` with `userId` on your server rather than with my Q&A. I handle this with quite complexity in my project since it's also a great way to detect duplicate users and potential fraud. But if you want SIMPLE solution you can send `registrationToken` along with username & password when user logs in and then that way associate device with user.